# Notify a group of a new issue in Redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I need to notify a group by email when a new issue is created in a project (only that group and not other users or group).

In alternative I could do this if I select a category (when filling a new issue), so it should cool to have a default category when opening a new issue.

Any suggestions on these points (best practices or plugins), please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the project's Settings > Information (tab) > Default assignee > select your group.

All members of the group will be notified via e-mail.

No plugin required.

Regards
Maxim

Comment: I am using redmine 3.4.3
I don't see the group but only member of groups.

Comment: https://redmine-domain/settings?tab=issues

Allow issue assignment to groups = checked?